# How to display "0" when using 'pluralize' in Django templates?

Tags: django, pluralize

Edit: The issue isn't related to `pluralize`. See comment.

How do I make `pluralize` to display 0? In the database are 2 book listings ('books'), 6 physical copies ('book_instances'), and 0 available for borrowing ('bookinstance_available'). In the code below, the first two display correctly: 2 and 6. The third line should display 0, but nothing appears. Is there anything I need to do for it to show 0 without writing special code (which seems to be the case when I searched)?

```
There are {{ num_books }} book{{ num_books|pluralize }} in the library catalog. <br>
There are {{num_bookinstance}} book{{num_bookinstance|pluralize}} in the collection. <br>
There are {{num_bookinstance_available}} book{{num_bookinstance_available|pluralize}} available for borrowing.
```

By the way, I'm working through the [Mozilla Django tutorial](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side/Django).

Comment: I don't understand your question. `Pluralize` is for adding a 's'. Do you mean the 's' is not appearing or `{{num_bookinstance_available}}` is not showing 0 ?

Comment: My bad-I conflated two different things. The plural 's' shows up no problem, but the 0 doesn't show up. Thank you for that!

Comment: Add your view so we can understand where `num_bookinstance_available` comes from.

Comment: @Guillaume Problem was indeed with the views (`num_bookinstance_available` wasn't defined correctly).  `pluralize` had nothing to do with the problem. I got the two mixed up. Your comment alerted me to that.